# How to manipulate an input field if a check box is checked

Tags: css

I m having problem with css of a tooltip. Tooltip belongs to an input field and if an other checkbox is checked, this tooltip needs to be placed correctly on the input field. so the check box is :

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="telefonBox" />
```

and the input field which tooltip needs to be placed :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control tooltip-berater" id="agentName"/>
```

What i tried is

```
input[id=telefonBox]:checked + .tooltip-berater + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {top: 875px !important; left: 30px; max-width:300px;}
```

(Basically i m trying to write: if a checkbox with this id checked, then do some stuff in this css classes)
But doesnt function at all. What am i missing?

Comment: You need to provide HTML code if your problem is about selectors, otherwise how can we know how to properly select elements you need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both inputs are children of the same div, but not directly next to each other (in the HTML markup) then you need to use `~` operator instead of `+`.

`+` works like:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second></div>
</div

.first + .second {
  // do stuff with second
}
```

`~` works like:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="inbetween"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</div

.first ~ .second {
  // you can still do stuff with second
}
```

There is no selector which would help you in other cases possible in your HTML markup, especially:

1. When .second div is placed earlier than .first
2. When .second div has different parent from .first

In those cases you will need to use JavaScript to select and change your element's CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a fiddle i made that changes colour of input box: https://jsfiddle.net/8we5u1vs/

Is that the kind of thing you want? Obviously its much simpler than what you're talking about. You havnt added much code so hard to tell, could you show code or fiddle for an example of the tooltip?

```
input[id=telefonBox]:checked + .tooltip-berater {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: yes exactly i m trying to do that but only a little bit complicated.. how much i see it works perfectly with only tooltip-berater class but if i add '.tooltip-berater + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {top: 375px}' then it is not working

Comment: How does the code for the tooltip appear? Do you even need tooltip-berator in there? How about swapping + .tooltip-berater in my example for just '+ .tooltip-inner' or + .'tooltip > .tooltip-inner'?

Comment: Dont think you can use '+' twice. Are you trying to apply this css to two elements or are they all nested within each other?

Comment: they are totally in different places

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, but text input is still available via <kbd>tab</kbd> key.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: white;
}

input[type=text] {
  border: 1px solid white;
  line-height: inherit;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: white;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + div span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type=checkbox>
<div>
  <input type=text>
  <span>N/A</span>
</div>
```